# While running bundle exec irb, need access to machine-only gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, irb

How do I make bundle exec irb aware of system-gems?

---

To load a project, we're using bundle exec irb. To make my life in irb a bit easier I had planned on using irb_rocket (with wirble and ruby-terminfo).

When loading just plain irb, it works as expected. However when using bundle exec irb, it can (obviously) not find my systems-gems.

I do not have the option to alter the gemfile, unless I can somehow make it only apply to my machine.

If it's worth anything; os x, source-control in git, ruby versioning in rbenv.

When requiring with the full paths of the gems, irb_rocket requires terminfo again which then throws a LoadError on `require 'terminfo.so'`. Changing the gem locally is not really what I want to do, but I guess it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry/) instead of IRB together with [pry-debundle](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/pry-debundle). If this is a Rails project you can just add [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) to your `Gemfile` so that it will be used as Rails console.

Comment: Switching to Pry doesn't give me the magic I am trying to achieve with  irb_rocket. While pry does allow me to work around bundler, I could not find options to adjust the display to that of irb_rocket's.  


Editing the gemfile is not an option.
It is not a rails project but we're using padrino (which opens irb)

Comment: @Xeago you should file an issue on Pry (https://github.com/pry/pry/issues) requesting an `irb_rocket` style plugin, it looks pretty trivial to implement

Comment: Problem would continue to exist because padrino console runs irb, not pry. However, I'll consider moving to pry if I find out how to make padrino run under pry.